# How to bind presentation of SwiftUI.Alert when triggered outside of the View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, combine

Most examples of showing `Alert` refer to some kind of `@State` being used as a binding that controls the *presented/hidden* state of the alert view.

As an example `showingAlert` ([source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-an-alert)):

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Important message"),
                message: Text("Wear sunscreen"),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!"))
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It's a good solution when the alert is triggered from the UI layer - as in the example:

```
Button(action: {
    self.showingAlert = true
}
```

**But what if we want to trigger it from the controller/viewmodel layer with a specific message?** As an example, we make a network call - the `URLSession`’s `Publisher` can send `Data` or an `Error` that we want to push to the user as a message in the `Alert`.

`@State` is designed to be managed from the view's `body`, so it seems that we should rather use an `@ObjectBinding` in this case. It seems that we also need some `message`, so we can reference it in the `body`:

```
Alert(
    title: Text("Important message"),
    message: Text(objectBinding.message)
)
```

The `showingAlert` would be a bit redundant here as we may define `message` as `String?` and create a binding for `presentation`:

```
Binding<Bool>(
    getValue: { objectBinding.message != nil },
    setValue: { if !$0 { objectBinding.message = nil } }
)
```

It's a doable approach and it works, but two things are making me a bit anxious:

1. The fact that `message` is managed by two abstractions
2. The information and management of the *presented/hidden* state of the alert leaked into controller/viewmodel/object binding. It'd be nice to keep the *presented/hidden* state privately in the view.
3. The fact that message is kept in the controller/viewmodel/object binding until it gets kind of "consumed" by the view (the binding).

**Can it be done better?**

Comment: Where is the source of truth? Despite the declaration that it's managed by two abstractions, there needs to be a single source. If not, then something else is wrong with what you are doing. (Paradigm shift?)

Comment: Thanks for your commment @dfd. More concrete example would be to delegate network request to the `objectBinding`. The `URLSession`’s `Publisher` (managed by the `objectBinding`) can send `Data` or an `Error`, so `objectBinding` is the source of truth for the error message. I’m not sure if it's a good practice to also keep the *presented/hidden* state of the `Alert` there

Comment: And yes - that's definitely a paradigm shift issue. In the imperative world, I'd just subscribe to that `Publisher`, pass error message, trigger an alert and call it a day - the *presented/hidden* state would be managed by the view itself and I wouldn't need to somehow cache the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to use Combine and it's publisher mechanism, you might be able to use `onReceive()`. Every generic SwiftUI View has [`onReceive()`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-onreceive) on it as a generic function that accepts a publisher, and when instantiated will subscribe to the publisher. It acts very similarly to the single-closure version of the Combine subscriber [`sink`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-sink) if you're familiar with that.

The specifics of the publisher expect a publisher Failure type of Never for this to work, so if you're working from Error's within some pipeline, you'll need to convert them to some other kind of object (perhaps an `Enum` with associated `String` values) and externalize them so they can be displayed with SwiftUI.

How you end up exposing the publisher to the SwiftUI view might be awkward as well - I've been doing it by adding a publisher onto a reference object with other `@Published` properties.

You can see a rough example of how this works (although not your specific use case) in [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) at https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#pattern-observableobject